# Plotting two longitudinal variables against time in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say I have a data that included two longitudinal variables `(x1, x2)`, `t` is time (years), and `type` is class:

```
set.seed(20)
x1 = rnorm(20,5,1) 
x2 = (x1 + rnorm(20))
t = rep(c(0,1,2,3), 5)
id = rep(1:5,each = 4)
type = as.factor(c(rep(0,8), rep(1,12)))
df = data.frame(id, t, x1, x2, type)
```

Is it possible to plot `x1` and `x2` agnist `t` in one plot? Actually, I am trying to see the relationship between `x1` and `x1` (but here use rnorm to make it easy) by modified the correlation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to treat the ID variable, but maybe try this?

```
require(reshape)
df <- reshape::melt(df, id.vars = c('id', 't', 'type'))
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = value, color = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image: ggplot]